# Is it possible to use 2 Crashlytics API keys?

Tags: android, ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

When I use Yandex.Metrica or Amplitude, it is possible to 2 or more different API Keys in same app.

Is it possible 2 make Fabric Crashlytics to use 2 different API keys in app AT SAME TIME. (preferable both iOS and Android apps)

Answer (score 1):

You could use switch between two (or more) api keys based on a build variant or flavor